# Scroll to top on click of onclick cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 tables set up, and on mobile I hide one and show the other `onclick` of a `tablerow` or icon, I need to have offset position set to top when I click, but having issues getting this done

When I click on this HTML

```
<a title="" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="updateStarter('1137','')"></a>
```

I want the shown table to open up at top of `div#right-head`

When I click on this HTML

```
<tr class="eventablerow" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showLineupTab(1,true)"></tr>
```

I want the shown table to open up at top of `div#left-head`

I have this working on one, but I wanted to be more specific to the `a` and `tr` for both instances when I click as I have other data in the tables you can click on, and when you do it causes `scrollTo` top to trigger

```
var jump = $(this).attr('href');
var new_position = $('#left-head').offset();
window.scrollTo(new_position.left,new_position.top);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm not sure of the real position of your table and `div#right-head` but I can suggest you to try this:

```
$(' a , tr').click(function(){
    var jump = $(this).attr("href");
    var _top = $("#left-head").offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop":_top+"px"}, 1000);
    return true;
});
```